# passing in custom class as arg in init

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to pass in a custom object to populate my view

```
class ViewController : UIViewController { 
   convenience init() {
      self.init(data: CustomObject) <----- Error: Cannot convert value of type  'CustomObject.Type' to expected argument type CustomObject
    }

    init (data: CustomObject) {
       self.data = data
       super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Usually if I'm passing in an array I just pass in an empty array like below

```
    convenience init() {
      self.init(data: [])  
    }

    init (data: Array<String>) {
       self.data = data
       super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
```

But since I'm passing in a custom object I'm not sure what to place there

Comment: maybe `self.init(data: CustomObject())` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently passing the type, not an actual object of that type. Assuming your `CustomObject` has a initializer without any arguments use:

```
convenience init() {
    self.init(data: CustomObject()) // create an instance and pass it along
}
```